# How Do I Change Properties of an Existing Twilio Number?

Tags: php, api, twilio

When I am purchasing a phone number via twilio I can setup various properties for the phone number like this:

```
$sid = 'AC...';
$token = '8...';
$number = '+12345678901';

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$response = $client->account->incoming_phone_numbers->create(
    array(
        "PhoneNumber" => $number,
        "FriendlyName" => "My Company Line",
        "VoiceUrl" => "http://testsite.com-callback-url-1.xml",
        "VoiceMethod" => "GET"
    )
);
```

**How do I Edit and Existing Number Details?**

For example, I want to change the number details to something else. Say `FriendlyName` to `My Personal Line`, `Voice_url` to `http://testsite.com-callback-url-2.xml` and `VoiceMethod` to `POST`.

Comment: Just change them in array

Comment: you mean I just call the `create()` function again with the existing phone number?

Comment: At first I misunderstood you question, look at answer I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dig more thoroughly into the [Twilio API description](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#instance-post).

You should use another API call for information updating. Here is the sample code for update:

```
$number = $client->account->incoming_phone_numbers->get("PN2a0747eba6abf96b7e3c3ff0b4530f6e");

$number->update(array(
    "FriendlyName " => "My Personal Line",
    "Voice_url" => "http://testsite.com-callback-url-2.xml",
    "VoiceMethod " => "POST"
    ));
```

If I understand correctly `$client->account->incoming_phone_numbers->create` already returns you the phone number object, so you just have to rename `$response` in your code to `$number` and call `update` method (without calling `client->account->incoming_phone_numbers->get`).